# PHP $_SESSION value is not setting correctly

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a simple login page in PHP which looks up the provided username and password in a mysql database and sets the php $_SESSION variable if the user is found. It works fine mostly, except that $_SESSION['user_type_id'] has a value of 1 no matter what value of $row[0]["user_type_id"].

var_dump ($row[0]["user_type_id"]) in the code below confirms that it has the correct value,  var_dump($_SESSION) (alongside the first var_dump) shows that $_SESSION['user_type_id'] is always 1.

The $row value is an int while the $_SESSION value is a string, I don't know if this is relevant. The only thing I can think of is that I'm resetting the session variable somewhere else but I don't recall doing that and I can't find it happening anywhere.

I'm trying to use this value to control permissions. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Here is the session code

```
public static function new_session ($username, $pw, $inactive) {

    $db = mydb::getConnection();

    $statement = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :parameter1 AND `password` = :parameter2');
    $statement->bindValue(':parameter1', $username);
    $statement->bindValue(':parameter2', $pw);
    $statement->execute();
    $row = $statement->fetchAll();

    var_dump ($row[0]["user_type_id"]);

    if (count($row) == 1) {

        session_start();
        ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60 * 20);

        $_SESSION['name'] = $row[0]['username'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row[0]['id'];
        $_SESSION['user_type_id'] = $row[0]["user_type_id"];

        $_SESSION['max'] = $inactive;
        $_SESSION['timeout'] = time() + $inactive;
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;

        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Here is the output of var_dump ($row[0]['user_type_id'])

```
int(500)
```

And here is the output of var_dump ($_SESSION['user_type_id'])

```
string(1) "1"
```

EDIT: below is the output of var_dump($result), as suggested below by @user3314428

```
array(5) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(2)
  ["user_type_id"]=>
  int(500)
  ["username"]=>
  string(5) "shane"
  ["password"]=>
  string(8) "***"
  ["email"]=>
  string(13) "***@***.**"
```

}

var_dump ($_SESSION['user_type_id'] is still string(1) "1"

Comment: just try using single quotes instead of double quotes in $row[0]["user_type_id"];
Im not sure at all,but please try it.

Comment: Thanks @VaisakhPc, it's not that though, I've tried all sorts of quotes and just went to doubles when copying the variable name directly from the var_dump to ensure I had it correct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't what causing problem here. But usually i use this type of format for login.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION) session_start();    
public static function new_session ($username, $pw, $inactive) {

$db = mydb::getConnection();

$statement = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :parameter1 AND `password` = :parameter2');
$statement->bindValue(':parameter1', $username);
$statement->bindValue(':parameter2', $pw);
$statement->execute();
if($statement->rowCount()==1)
{
  $result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $_SESSION['user_type_id']=$result['user_type_id'];
  $_SESSION['var2']= $result['var2'];
  //and so on
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The function works and the id and username are set correctly, it's just the user_type_id value that is not being set correctly.

Comment: still having problems??

Comment: Yes! Same thing. I've left alone for the moment, maybe the problem will become obvious later...

Comment: try var_dump($result) and comment output here.

Comment: I have added the var_dump($result)  output to the original post

Answer (score 0):

session_start() should be at the TOP of the page, not inside the function

Comment: that's only a personal preference, nothing to do with making it work. A lot of web page incorrectly say it must be the first line in a php file, which is just wrong, and unfortunately spread all over the web

Comment: In this case it is already called at the start of every page. I've taken that line out of the function, it still seems to work ok (apart from the one bit that isn't working)